# Why is my IF statement skipped?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

My android application is skipping an IF statement:

```
 Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.UK);
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(curLatitude, curLongitude,1);

            if (addresses.size() > 0) //this is skipped
            {
                StringBuilder cityName = new StringBuilder();                
                cityName.append(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                CityName = cityName.toString();
```

It was working fine yesterday and today for some unknown  reasons its skipped. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Your `addresses.size()`  is not greater than zero. Check how many elements it consists.

Comment: Debugging is your friend

Comment: Use  if (addresses.size() !=null)

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to two reasons:

1. In the lines before the `IF` statement an `Exception` is thrown.
2. `addresses` has no elements

You should check `addresses` length and capture any possible `Exception` to know the reason why is your  conditional not executed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29) method `getFromLocation`

> Returns a list of Address objects. Returns **null or empty list** if no
>   matches were found or there is no backend service available.

It means that you pass coordinate that not contains any addresses.

Answer (score 0):

- You're certainly getting an Exception ("Service unavailable").
- Or maybe you reached a limit by sending too much requests ?

Take a look here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009

Answer (score 0):

Your adresses object may have following issues        1)adresses may be null so nullpointer exception may happen  2)your addresses list have no element so it may return 0 always